Cannot enable Desktop & Documents Folders on MacBook M3
I have bought a new Macbook m3 but somehow I cannot sync desktop & documents folders. The option would not let me turn it on, it goes back to being off. Im new to MacBook, so I don't what's really wrong. Someone help? Thank in advance

Have you set up an AppleID account?

Yes i did set up an appleid.

You've followed Apple's steps, as described here? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/109344

Obviously. I tried to turn it on but its not possible.
